# how to replace bbcode li?

Tags: php, regex

I need to create a function to replace

```
[li]text[/li]
```

into

```
 <li>text</li>
```

This is the regex Im testing but nothing

```
 $string="[li]A[/li] [li]B[/li] [li]C[/li] [li]D[/li]";

 $pattern = "/[li](.*?)[\/li]/s";
$string = preg_replace($pattern, "$1", $string);

 echo $string; //but returns: []A[/] []B[/] []C[/] []D[/]
```

but nothing, **what Im doing wrong?**

Comment: Square brackets in regexp are special. You need to escape those too.

Comment: scaping and using this new regex puts everything within a single li `/\[li\](.*?)\[\/li\]/s`

Comment: Should `[li]text` without `[/li]` be altered? Can we assume that if `[/li]` is present it will be preceded by `[li]`? Is it just `[li]`, or, could it be, say, `[a]` and `[/a]`?

Answer (score 1):

you should insert the < li > in the replace command

```
$string="[li]A[/li] [li]B[/li] [li]C[/li] [li]D[/li]";
$pattern = "/\[li\](.*?)\[\/li\]/s";
$string = preg_replace($pattern, "<li>$1</li>", $string);
echo "<pre>";
echo $string;
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Thank you. what if within one or several     `li` are there linebreaks? thank you

Comment: you could do another command at beggining of code to replace \n like $string = preg_replace("/(\n)/", "", $string);

Comment: Newlines shouldn't affect it. They're just characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string="[li]A[/li] [li]B[/li] [li]C[/li] [li]D[/li]";
$string = preg_replace('/\[(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/(.*?)\]/', '<$1>$2</$3>', $string);
echo $string;
```

Result:

```
<li>A</li> <li>B</li> <li>C</li> <li>D</li>
```